# Prove $\lim_{x\to a}\sqrt{x}=\sqrt{a}$ by definition Stewart solution error

Tags: calculus

Let $a>0$. I want to show
$$\lim_{x\to a}\sqrt{x}=\sqrt{a}$$

Purpose of this question was to investigate Stewart's online solution, which turns out to be incorrect.

[Their solution](http://www.stewartcalculus.com/media/11_inside_homework_hints.php?show_cat=2&book=7et&hint_id=h00578)

I don't understand the solution on their website. Are they saying that

$1/x  < x $? Seems that way to me by the way they choose delta.

**My solution :**

$$|x-a|< a   \implies   \frac{1}{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{a}} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}$$
and choose delta accordingly. Is that correct?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcome to the community.  I suggest you pose your question directly rather than posting a link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to discuss the inequality $|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{a}|<\varepsilon$.

Now take $\delta=\min(\varepsilon\sqrt{a},a)$ and assume $|x-a|<\delta$. Since $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a}>\sqrt{a}$, we have
$$
|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{a}|=
\frac{|x-a|}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a}}<
\frac{|x-a|}{\sqrt{a}}<\frac{\delta}{\sqrt{a}}\le\varepsilon
$$

Comment: Yes, now I see my mistake. Thank you; I totally forgot the proper choice.

Comment: I spent a lot of time trying to figure out why the Stewart solution chose delta to be  epsilon/[(sqrt(a)*(sqrt(2) +1)] still doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: It's just any choice. As you do these, you learn how to make the proper choice of $\delta.$ When you take a course in advanced calculus (usually in your third year), you'll really get used to these arguments.

The choice really comes from doing some scratch work in the beginning, too small to explain in this box.

Comment: a>0 by hypothesis

Comment: I see how they get : sqrt(a)+sqrt(x) <= sqrt(a)*[sqrt(2) +1]. But their choice of delta seems incorrect. http://www.stewartcalculus.com/media/11_inside_homework_hints.php?show_cat=2&book=7et&hint_id=h00578

Comment: @sps This bound is correct, but useless.

Comment: It is a mistake.  They went from $|\frac 1{\sqrt x + \sqrt a}||x-a|$ in one line to $|\sqrt x + \sqrt a||x-a|$ in the next.  Furthermore, suppose, $a = 1, \epsilon = 0.1$ then $\delta < (1+\sqrt 2)\epsilon \approx 0.2414, x$ could be as small as $0.7587$ and $| \sqrt {0.7587} - 1| > 0.11$

Comment: @Doug M Thank you! I spent so much time thinking why their solution was correct!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the outline for this style of proof:
Prove 
$\lim_\limits {x\to a} \sqrt x = \sqrt a$

What is the definition of "limit"?

$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta >0$ such that $|x-a|< \delta \implies |\sqrt x - \sqrt a| < \epsilon$

What algebraic manipulations do we need to do to express $|\sqrt x - \sqrt a|$ as a multiple of $\delta$?

$|\sqrt x - \sqrt a| = |\frac {x-a}{\sqrt x + \sqrt a}|$

$\sqrt x + \sqrt a > \sqrt a$

If $a\ne 0$ we can say when $\delta < \sqrt a\epsilon, |\sqrt x - \sqrt a|<\epsilon.$

But what about when $a = 0$? In this case, a two-sided limit does not exist.

There is a neighborhood of the domain around $a$ that maps arbitrarily close to $\sqrt a$

Answer (score -2):

Your reasoning does not seem correct (honestly, I really can't follow it). Here's what I have.

**Proof.** Let $\epsilon > 0.$ Choose $\delta = \epsilon |\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a}|.$ Then when $|x - a| < \delta,$

\begin{align*}
|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{a} | &= \frac{x-a}{|\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a}|} \\
&< \frac{\delta}{|\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{a} |} \\
&< \epsilon
\end{align*}

as required.

I welcome any refinements.

Comment: $\delta$ cannot depend on $x$.